# How to get my channels list on Youtube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get all channels that I have on a youtube account.

For example I have 3 channels on a account. [image: 3 channels on my account]

What I've done:

1. Read the documentation on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list.
2. Authenticate with my account
3. Send GET request to GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
4. I got success response, without error. But I only get a channel. I expected to get all my channels (3 channels).

Is it possible to get all my channels? If possible what should I do to get it?

Answer (score 0):

After sometime searching for the same question, 
I found this [YouTube API v3 get all channels associated with a logged in user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072799/youtube-api-v3-get-all-channels-associated-with-a-logged-in-user)

And that is true.
Apparently, Youtube has no user info, but a channel info. So, when a user gives you permission to read his/her Youtube info, you only got permission to read a specific channel info (the "mine" channel) that was selected on the Google Account permission page.

The other user's channels will be seen as any other channel.

btw, I am not 100% of this, that's what I understood after reading the Youtube Data Api V3.