# how to get ALL your channel-IDs - youtube api v3

Tags: python, api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I was wondering if it was possible to gain your other channel-IDs, this code under is only getting one channelID (the one channel i clicked on during the authorization).

```
 def gaining_channelID(youtube):
     channels_list_response = youtube.channels().list(
     part="id",
     mine=True
     ).execute()
    channelid= ""

    for list in channels_list_response["items"]:
          channelid= list["id"]
          print(channelid)
    return channelid
```

And can i upload videos to your other channels? Or do i HAVE to go through the the authorization again and choose a different channel i want to upload to?

right now it seems like that's the only way

ive been watching this and it said so, but was wondering if it had changed (since that was 2 years ago the question was asked)

[YouTube API v3 get all channels associated with a logged in user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072799/youtube-api-v3-get-all-channels-associated-with-a-logged-in-user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you authenticate to the YouTube API you pick a channel.  In my case I have 6 channels I think.   If I authenticate to the first channel I will only have access to the first channels data.

Yes you need to authenticate for each of the channels.  The access you get will be channel specific.