# How to fetch youtube channel list of loggedin user

Tags: youtube-api, objective-c-blocks, youtube-data-api

I want to fetch the youtube channel list and show it on tableView can anyone help to get the channel list of loggedin user via google.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) method which returns a collection of zero or more `channel` resources that match the request criteria. Then use the [`forUsername`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#parameters) parameter.

> The `forUsername` parameter specifies a YouTube username, thereby requesting the channel associated with that username.

Additional reference:

- [YouTube API v3 get all channels associated with a logged in user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072799/youtube-api-v3-get-all-channels-associated-with-a-logged-in-user)